# problem with a hard drive

Tags: external-hdd

Well I have an external WD HDD hard drive the format of which I've changed to FAT32 in order to work with my tv. Generally it worked very well and Ubuntu used to recognise it very quickly but today when I was unzipping a file into the hard drive, after a lot of time it crashed and plus my hard drive was not recognised any more. I connected it to the tv and after a LOT of time the light started to blink but it caused the tv to crash (when a unplugged it, it was ok). The I  tried again on my pc and after some time the icon of the disk appeared on the launcher but when I as clinking it it didn't respond. Plus when I try to use the disk program it crashes and only when I unplug the drive it responds. I really need help, I have some really important file in there.Sorry for the but english. Thank you

Comment: I just tried it on an old windows 7 pc and much to my surprise it did worked, the computer recognised it and thankfully all of my files are there but when it came to open a folder, either it took to much time to do it (if it was a small one) either it did not make it and crashed. Any ideas?

Comment: From Windows, do a check of the file system, and a defrag.

Comment: You can use the diagnostic utility from your BIOS or check the disk for errors from Windows(chkdsk)

Comment: This is not available for Ubuntu?

Comment: it doesn't work. I click on start an d then it does not do anything

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a typical hard drive failure. I would back up all data on the hard drive ASAP, so that all of your files are safe before running any diagnostic software, as it may shorten the life span dramatically, or render it useless.

I would then recommend running a file system check on the drive. This can be done on your Windows computer by right clicking on your external hard drive and select "Properties". Then go to "Tools" > "Error checking".

You may also want to try out the different diagnostic and repair tools on this rescue cd, called [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com). I've used it numerous times, and it's a very handy suite!